# <django.utils.functional.SimpleLazyObject object at 0x2b4d1fe47650> is not JSON serializable

Tags: json, django

I have a Django app. In the view I call another function (in stats.py) which then makes a HTTP POST.

**views.py**

```
  from stats import Stat
  a = Stat(example="12345")
  a.use(id='query')
```

**stats.py**

```
   self.data = { example : "12345" }

   req = urllib2.Request(api_url)
   req.add_header('Content-Type', 'application/json')
   response = urllib2.urlopen(req, json.dumps(self.data))
```

The problem that occurs is that I get the error,

```
<django.utils.functional.SimpleLazyObject object at 0x2b4d1fe47650> is not JSON serializable
```

**Django Traceback**

From looking at the Django Traceback I get the following,

```
 /prod/tools/lx/views.py in update_input

            a.use(id='query')

     ...

/prod/tools/main/stats.py in log_use

            response = urllib2.urlopen(req, json.dumps(self.data))

     ...

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py in dumps

            return _default_encoder.encode(obj)

     ...

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py in encode

            chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)

     ...

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py in iterencode

            return _iterencode(o, 0)

     ...

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py in default

            raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")

     ...
```

Any ideas ?

Thanks,

Comment: Why is this marked down, and voted for a close ?

Comment: What is `self.data`?

Comment: the class that is in stats.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this using `urllib`

```
import urllib
...
    self.data = { example : "12345", 'Content-type':'application/json' }    
    self.data = urllib.urlencode(self.data)
    req = urllib2.Request(api_url, self.data)
    response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
```

Comment: test in shell OP code from stats.py (for example with api_url 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/') it works ... , so seems problem is not there

Comment: That returns HTTP Error 400: BAD REQUEST

Comment: This error comes when data stream sent to the server is wrong or invalid, try now

Comment: Also make sure value of `self.data` is correct and no extra header is required